# Android WindowManager shows same screen size for different devices

Tags: android, screen-size, android-windowmanager

I am debugging my application on 2 different Droid devices: Bionic and Droid3.  When I use WindowManager to display device width & height, it shows 540x960 (portrait) and 960x540 (landscape) for both devices!  How is that possible?  The 2 devices are clearly of a different size.  Here is the code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final int width = display.getWidth();
final int height = display.getHeight();
```

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 1):

I read that getWidth()/getHeight() is deprecated.
Try to use this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point displayDimensionInPixel = new Point();
display.getSize(displayDimensionInPixel);
```

I'm not shure right now because the Documentation isn't [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) anymore, but I think I can remember that getWidth()/getHeight() of Display dont return pixel dimensions.

Comment: getSize() is not a method of Display.  Did you mean something else?

Comment: on which API level you are developing? Be shure to check "Filter by API level" on the Bottom right and but it on 14. its the second-last method.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have Eclipse installed right here. Try to find out what dimensions are returned exactly. As the Documentation is generated out of the Code, you might get the 2.1 Documentation in Eclipse's autocompletion-feature. you can refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html this to find out how to convert after. Also Note that the sdk isn't compiled into the app. Unfortunatly it might be the case that Motorola might pass some other dimensions that HTC, where they shouldn't